# Connection between Joukowsky transform and elliptic coordinate system

Tags: transformation, coordinate-systems

The [Joukowsky transformation](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2016/01/31/joukowsky-transformation/) with $z = x+i y$
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)
$$
maps circles to ellipses. I wonder what is the connection of this transform to the [Elliptic coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_coordinate_system) ?
$$
x = a \ \cosh \mu \ \cos \nu \\
y = a \ \sinh \mu \ \sin \nu
$$

Answer (score 1):

We may parametrise the $z$-plane without zero by the "exponential polar coordinates" $z=e^{u+iv}$, where $u \in \mathbb{R}$ and $0 \leqslant v < 2\pi$. Examining the effect that $z \mapsto w = f(z)$ has on this, we find
$$ f(e^{u+iv}) = \frac{1}{2}(e^{u+iv}+e^{-u-iv}) = \cosh{(u+iv)} = \cosh{u}\cos{v}+i\sinh{u}\sin{v}, $$
which are elliptic coordinates with $a=1$. Replacing the Joukowsky transform with $(z+a^2/z)/2$ and using polar coordinates $ae^{u+iv}$ instead gives the more general elliptic coordinates with $a \neq 1$.